# Do I need publisher policy files?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-2.0

I'm quite new to .NET development and have to take over a library consisting of several DLL files. I have seen that with the packaging process of the library (for creating the installer) there are publisher assembly policy files for the assemblies created, like in this example: [How to: Create a Publisher Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-create-a-publisher-policy).

So, basically these policies are used to redirect to newer assemblies. However, coming from the Java world, I find this procedure tedious. It means that with every minor version change I have to adopt the publisher policies of all assemblies?

Now I wonder if this is really necessary because this behavior seems awkward to me. In the company nobody knows about this as well and can't tell why it's originally in the library.

Further question: I've created a new version of the library (without creating the policy files) and installed the assemblies. It seems that I need to add new references to my projects in Visual Studio for the upgraded DLLs. Is this behavior expected? Is the benefit of the publisher policiy files that I don't need to re-link my references in the projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test porpuses I removed the policy files from the library and didn't notice any bad impact so far. I had to re-link a few assemblies but nothing really to worry about. Also guessing from the absence of answers here on SO that these files are outdated and shall not be used anymore.